# Assign interface type to code-first GraphQL resolver argument

Tags: typescript, graphql

The following code-first GraphQL schema example is taken from GraphQL's [Constructing Types](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/) page.

```
// Define the Query type
var queryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      // `args` describes the arguments that the `user` query accepts
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: (_, {id}) => {
        return fakeDatabase[id];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Although you are able to define the args and their GraphQL types (GraphQLString in this example), the actual id property within the resolver has an "any" type.

I tried replacing `{id}` with `{id}: {id: string}` but that threw the error `Type '(_: any, { id }: { id: string; })' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLFieldResolver<any, any, { [argName: string]: any; }>'`.

Although this is a simple "string" example, my actual code has more complex object types with multiple properties. Ensuring the correct property name is referenced is a big help elsewhere that is missing within the resolvers. Perhaps there is a way to tell the resolver the actual types of the args but I'm too new to TypeScript to find it.

Is there a way to define/override the types of the resolvers args?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are having the same problem outlined in [this issue](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2829).

A workaround is to make your `id` property optional (by replacing `{id}` with `{id}: {id?: string}`) and check for its existence within the resolver before you reference it.

Comment: Thanks! Seems this issue is fixed as of Oct 2021 and looks to be included in the 16.0.0 release of the graphql-js library.